# How to know which stored procedures are running in an Oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I need to know which stored procedures are running. It's not an option to "mark" the stored procedures changing their source.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This blogpost of mine tells you all about it: http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2008/11/executingpackagessql.html

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: +1... nice  - I hadn't considered the v$session plsql_entry_object_id and plsql_entry_subprogram_id limitations that you discuss

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about doing that for the entire database, but did you try using DBMS_TRACE?

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_trace.htm#CACEIHAH